# msw (mock service worker) is always in loading state even after await with react-testing-library

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, msw

## SOLVED

ARRGGHHH

Turns out graphql fragments don't play well with msw. Dear god shoot me, that's 5h I won't get back.

---

I have a mock graphql server setup with msw, with the basic setup below that I import into my test file:

```
// Setup requests interception using the given handlers.
export const server = setupServer(...handlers);

export function setup() {
    beforeAll(() => {
        // Enable the mocking in tests.
        server.listen();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        // Ensure Apollo cache is cleared between tests.
        // https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.clearStore
        return client.clearStore();
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        // Reset any runtime handlers tests may use.
        server.resetHandlers();
    });

    afterAll(() => {
        // Clean up once the tests are done.
        server.close();
    });
}
```

I can confirm that my query is indeed being intercepted, and indeed the return too

```
    graphql.query('getAgenda', (req, res, ctx) => {
        console.debug('in handlers')
        const { id } = req.variables;

        if (id === '1') {
            console.debug('returning res')
            return res(
                ctx.data({
                    agenda,
                })
            );
        }
    }),
```

As I get this output

```
  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:70:10)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:71:10)

  console.debug
    in handlers

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:8:11)

  console.debug
    returning res

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:12:11)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:70:10)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:71:10)

  console.debug
    in handlers

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:8:11)

  console.debug
    returning res

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:12:11)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:70:10)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:71:10)

  console.debug
    in handlers

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:8:11)

  console.debug
    returning res

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:12:11)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:70:10)

  console.debug
    undefined

      at Component (src/pages/Agenda/ViewAgenda.js:71:10)

  console.debug
    in handlers

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:8:11)

  console.debug
    returning res

      at resolver (src/__tests__/__mocks__/handlers.js:12:11)
```

The undefined output is where I'm trying to console.debug(data), and when in the debugger I can also see that data is never resolved!

Here's the test

```
    it('matches its returned data snapshot', async () => {
        const history = createMemoryHistory();
        history.push('/agenda/1');
        const { asFragment } = render(<ViewAgenda />, { wrapperProps: { history }});


        await screen.findByText('Planerat mötesdatum');
        expect(asFragment(<ViewAgenda />)).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```

I do use the `await screen`... also I've confirmed it's not something to do with the router, as the handler is fired correctly for the route and the console.debug is fired from within the component I'm trying to mount.

How do I go about starting to debug this?! Why isn't data resolving?

Comment: Hey. I'm sorry to hear about 5h wasted. Let's save others those hours by submitting an issue to the MSW's repo on GitHub regarding those fragments? Afaik, it should support them with no issues.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up continuing down the rabbit hole thinking "I can't be the only one to have encountered this". Supposedly fragments in the query should have worked if I had the __typename's in the mocks, but I have not confirmed. Either way, I like the library and hold no grudge today.

Comment: Also, the loading state did switch to resolved when every field in the query was returned by the mock, it just cleared it because of the fragment. So, for me, it was a two-step solution of checking queried fields against mocks and then removing the fragment.

Comment: Yeah, you need to remember that the actual response resolution is still dependent on the GraphQL client you're using. For example, Apollo will _not_ return any response if the mocked JSON misses the `__typename` keys. We do mention this in the [GraphQL response resolver](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/mocks/graphql-api#response-resolver) part of the tutorial.

Comment: I recognise that part in the tutorial, but seeing as I had tests resolving without `__typename` I didn't think too much about it :( anyway, thank you for the response and keep it up 

Comment: Since you solved this yourself would you mind adding the solution as an answer and marking it solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Cathal Mac Donnacha's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3472935/cathal-mac-donnacha) request, the solution was to not use graphql fragments. The solution I used was to use string interpolation.